# Setting the holographic theme in Honeycomb

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I saw this post about using the new holographic themes on Honeycomb:
[Change theme according to android version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865724/change-theme-according-to-android-version)

In my app, I have minSdkVersion="11" and targetSdkVersion="11". By default, I get a solid black background with light text. If I explicitly set Theme.Holo, on either application or activity, I still get the solid black, using this:

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"

However, I think Theme.Holo uses the gradient background I see in the HoneycombGallery example, set like this:

```
  case R.id.toggleTheme:
       if (mThemeId == android.R.style.Theme_Holo) {
            mThemeId = android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light;
       } else {
            mThemeId = android.R.style.Theme_Holo;
  }
```

If that's the real holographic theme, how do I get it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will get the fancy background only when hardware acceleration is turned on.

Comment: Wonderful. I set android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in my AndroidManifest, and it worked. TYVVM ...

Comment: Is there any way to disable this fancy background while keeping HW acceleration?

Comment: Just set your theme's windowBackground to null or remove it manually from the window.

Comment: How to get Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar in honeycomb?