# Inherit from @android:style/Theme.Holo.Light in a minSdkVersion="4" application

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I currently have an Android application targeting version 11 of the SDK with a minimum version of 4. I would like to apply the Light version of the Holo theme if the app is running on Honeycomb. Following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865724/change-theme-according-to-android-version) I have tried adding the following to res/values-v11/themes.xml but my application will not compile because @android:style/Theme.Holo.Light does not exist in SDK 4

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    </style>
</resources>
```

Is is possible to get a reference to that theme without having to build separate 1.6-2.x and 3.x versions of my application?

Comment: Setting minimum SDK to 4 in the manifest doesn't mean you have to set the build target to 4 - you can leave that at 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As EboMike pointed out in the comments this was a problem with setting the build target to the Minimum SDK version instead of the Target SDK version.