# NavigationView - Setting `app:itemBackground` causes menu items to lose start padding

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, navigationview, android-navigationview

I am running into an issue when setting the `app:itemBackground` for the NavigationView. I am trying to create a custom background for the selected menu item. The custom background works, but when I use it, it seems to kill the start padding of the menu items.

Without the background(default)

[image]

With the custom background
[image]

You can see that the menu items are flush to the left of the menu when the `itemBackground` is set.

Here is the relevant xml...

layout

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">
<!-- your content layout -->
    <include
        layout="@layout/MainLayout" />
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/primary_color"
        android:id="@+id/NavigationView"
        app:itemTextColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigationheaderlayout"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/navigation_item_selector"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

selector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/navigation_item_selected_background" android:state_selected="true" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/navigation_item_selected_background" android:state_pressed="true" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/navigation_item_selected_background" android:state_checked="true" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/navigation_item_not_selected_background" />
</selector>
```

selected backgroud

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item 
        android:left="0dp" 
        android:right="2dp" 
        android:drawable="@color/accent_color" />

    <item 
        android:left="2dp" 
        android:right="2dp" 
        android:drawable="@color/navigation_selected_item_color" />
</layer-list>
```

not selected background

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item>
       <shape android:shape="rectangle">
           <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
       </shape>
   </item>
</layer-list>
```

Has anybody run into something like this before?

Comment: You need to leave 1 blank line between your paragraph and the code. I had it fixed before your edit :)

Comment: Thanks...I was wondering what the hell was going on

Comment: IMHO you override some defaults by using the drawable. The only way I know to see what happens id to use [stetho](https://code.facebook.com/posts/393927910787513/stetho-a-new-debugging-platform-for-android/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please note below solution will work for pre-lollipop versions. But will add extra padding in lollipop and above. Please apply different theme for different versions to avoid this.**

After setting app:theme, padding left issue is fixed.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        android:background="@drawable/your_menu_bg"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/your_menu_item_bg"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        app:theme="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/your_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
```

This is my custom theme.

```
<style name="NavigationDrawerStyle">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">20dp</item>
</style>
```

How to apply different themes for different versions? Check the other link below.

[Change theme according to android version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865724/change-theme-according-to-android-version)

Comment: Awesome. I will test this out tonight.

Comment: @RyanAlford was this solution working for you? I'm facing the same problem and this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Add for Android 4 versions a padding at the **end** of the layer-list in your drawable.

Like this way:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item 
        android:left="0dp" 
        android:right="2dp" 
        android:drawable="@color/accent_color" />

    <item 
        android:left="2dp" 
        android:right="2dp" 
        android:drawable="@color/navigation_selected_item_color" />
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <padding android:left="12dp" android:right="12dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```